# Can't declare an abstract method private

Tags: java, oop

I want to do this, yet I can't. Here is my scenario and rational. I have an abstract class for test cases that has an abstract method called test(). The test() method is to be defined by the subclass; it is to be implemented with logic for a certain application, such as `CRMAppTestCase extends CompanyTestCase`. I don't want the test() method to be invoked directly, I want the super class to call the test() method while the sub class can call a method which calls this (and does other work too, such as setting a current date-time right before the test is executed for example). Example code:

```
public abstract class CompanyTestCase {
    //I wish this would compile, but it cannot be declared private
    private abstract void test();

    public TestCaseResult performTest() {
        //do some work which must be done and should be invoked whenever 
        //this method is called (it would be improper to expect the caller
        // to perform initialization)
       TestCaseResult result = new TestCaseResult();
       result.setBeginTime(new Date());
       long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
       test(); //invoke test logic
       result.setDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
       return result;
    }
}
```

Then to extend this....

```
public class CRMAppTestCase extends CompanyTestCase {

    public void test() {
        //test logic here
    }

}
```

Then to call it....

```
TestCaseResult result = new CRMAppTestCase().performTest();
```

Comment: Just a side note, the date/time that the CRMAppTestCase is instantiated and the time that it is ran can be VERY different since they could be queued or put into a threadpool to be executed in the future.

Comment: is there a reason why you are re-inventing JUnit?

Comment: its not reinventing considering that test() isn't a junit method. This really has to do with selenium, but that is off topic.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Private methods are not polymorphic (you cannot inherit them), so it makes no sense to make a private method abstract. Making a method abstract means you'd have to override and implement it in a subclass, but since you can't override private methods, you can't make them abstract either.

You should make it `protected` instead of `private`.

Private really means private to the class you've defined the method in; even subclasses don't see private methods.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to point out that it is the **choice of Java** not to let abstract private methods implemented (e.g. in C++ you can [and is advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170688/private-virtual-method-in-c)). Saying that private methods are not polymorphic in general is just ignorant of the fact that calling and defining a method is two different mechanism - although subclasses can never call a private method of a superclass, they could be able to define it. Mixing the two is a common misconception, please be aware.

I don't have enough reputation to comment, that's why I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to do this, yet I can't

Changing this will require rewriting the compiler, which isn't likely.

You realize why this can never work, right?  A subclass can't override a private method, yet, it's abstract which says they must.  Catch-22.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `private abstract` method because subclasses can't see private members of a superclass.  You need to make your `test` method `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

abstract means you'll want to define the method in a child class

private means the child classes won't see the method

How could it compile ?

If the method should end up public, declare it public abstract, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your "test" method as "protected" to achieve your goal. But it still will be accessible from the package of the class.