# When/why to make function private in class?

Tags: c++, oop, class-design, private-methods

When should i make a function `private` and why is it good idea?

Comment: I would vote up an answer that provide a concrete example. Currently the answers are not specific enough to argue against.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should make a function `private` when you don't need other objects or classes to access the function, when you'll be invoking it from within the class.

**Stick to the principle of least privilege**, only allow access to variables/functions that are absolutely necessary. Anything that doesn't fit this criteria should be `private`.

Answer (score 31):

I usually make the helper functions `private`. But what is *helper*  seems to be vague. So let me give you an example. Suppose you've the following class `Sample`; it exposes few public functions, one of them, say, is `DoWork()`. This function takes one parameter. But it doesn't assume that the parameter will always be valid, so it **first** checks the validity of parameter for which it has lots of code in the beginning of the function. Something like this:

```
class Sample
{
   public:
      void DoWork(SomeClass param)
      {
               /*
                *lots of code related to validation of param
                */  

                //actual code that operates on the param 
                //and other member data IF the param is valid
      }
};
```

Since you've written lots of code related to validation of the param, it makes the function cumbersome, and difficult to read. So you decided to move this validation code to function say, `IsValidParam()`, and then you call this function from `DoWork()` passing the parameter `param` to it. Something like this:

```
class Sample
{
   public:
      void DoWork(SomeClass param)
      {       
            if ( IsValidParam(param))       
            {
                //actual code that operates on the param 
                //and other member data IF the param is valid
            }
      }
};
```

That looks cleaner, right?

Okay, you've written `IsValidParam()` somewhere in the class, but the question you face now is, would you make this function `public`? If this function is used **only** by your other functions like `DoWork()`, then making `IsValidParam()` *public* doesn't make sense. So you decided to make this function `private`.

```
class Sample
{
   public:
      void DoWork(SomeClass param)
      {       
            if ( IsValidParam(param))       
            {
                //actual code that operates on the param 
                //and other member data IF the param is valid
            }
      }
  private:
      bool IsValidParam(SomeClass param)
      {
          //check the validity of param.
          //return true if valid, else false.
      }
};
```

Functions of this kind (IsValidParam) should be `private`. I call these functions *helper functions*.

Hope this explanation helps you!

Answer (score 7):

One of the founding principals of OOP is encapsulation. This is where functionality for how an object works is kept internal to that object. The idea is that it's easier for code to use an object if it doesn't need to know how it works. Kind of like buying a microwave--you just need to know how to use it and not how it works.

The same approach should be taken with OOP. Keep everything needed to maintain the object private. Make only what is needed to fully use the object public.

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing a class - considering the way client code should use it - then you will inevitably derive an interface consisting of `public` and perhaps `protected` members.

`private` members are functions and data that supports and enables those public/protected members.  `private` functions should factor and/or modularise/structure the code needed by the non-`private` members, making their implementation less redundant and easier to understand.

Summarily, you make a member `private` if it's not intended for direct use by client code, and only exists to support the non-`private` members.

Answer (score 1):

How purist do you want to be? :)

The proper answer to this question is related to the maintenance of invariants. The right way to do this is rather complicated.

In your base class you define public methods to provide the **whole** of the access to the class. All these methods must be concrete. The key thing here is that the public invariants are assumed to hold before and after calling these functions. These functions must never call each other, they call only protected and private methods. These functions should be axiomatic: they should be a fairly minimal set required to capture the desired semantics.

Most calculations which can be done using these methods should be global or at least public static members.

You also provide pure virtual methods which are hooks to implement the details depending on the representation in derived classes. Virtual functions in the base should be private. The usual advice here (public) is completely wrong. Virtual functions are implementation details. One exception: the virtual destructor must be public.

Private helper functions can also be put in the base.

It may be useful to have protected methods in the base too: these will call the private helpers or virtuals. As above: protected methods should never call protected or public methods. Protected functions maintain a weaker invariant than the public one before and after each call.

Private functions usually maintain very weak invariants.

The reason for this strict hierarchy is to ensure the object invariants are maintained correctly.

Now, in a derived class you provide an implementation. Ideally, the virtual functions here would be **invisible**, a stronger condition than merely private. These virtual functions should not be called at all in the derived class. The **only** permitted access is via protected functions of the base.

All methods of derived classes including the destructor should be private. Constructors must be public, but they're not methods of the class.

In order to fully understand these rules you must think carefully about invariants. The public invariants can be *assumed to hold* prior to calling a public method and are *required to hold* after it is finished. Therefore you cannot call such functions from inside the class nor any class derived from it, because those functions are used to modify the representation in-between the start and end of a public function, and so inevitably break the public invariants: that's why they must not call the public functions.

The same argument applies to protected functions: **functions can only call functions with weaker invariants**.

Virtual functions are always called by the public from the base class public wrappers to ensure the sequencing of operations, which breaks public invariants, is never interrupted by returning to the public with a broken invariant. The set of virtuals themselves represent the invariant structure any representation must have. By doing this all manipulations of the representation to perform calculations for public clients can be abstracted into the base.

In practice, these rules are not usually followed because they would often generate trivial wrappers and that's a lot of extra code to write and maintain. So virtual functions often end up being public, even when this is completely and utterly wrong in principle.

Comment: "Therefore you cannot call such functions from inside the class" - that doesn't follow. You can't call them *if the invariants don't hold at the time of the call*, but you can call them at points where you happen to know the class invariants do hold, which for example will be the case if the calling code hasn't modified any data members yet. For example, `std::string` has functions `size` and `length` which return exactly the same value. There's no particular reason why one can't be implemented to call the other and return the result. `size` does not "inevitably break the public invariants".

Comment: For a non-const example, consider `std::vector::pop_back`, which can quite reasonably be implemented by calling two other public members: `erase(--end())`. You're talking specifically about the implementation of the NVI idiom, in which by design every public function does nothing other than call a private virtual function. But that is not the only good way to write a class in C++, and its reason for making the virtual functions private is *not* so that they can be called while the object is in a state that violates its class invariants. They generally can't.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a function or class  we should understand scope of that function or class whether it is Globally or Locally.

eg:"ConnectionString ()".
 Every database connection needs "ConnectionString () " so its declared Public .

Answer (score 0):

private: only used by this class, not used by other classes nor derived classes.
protected: used by this class and maybe derived classes, but not used by other classes.
public: used by other class, this class, and derived class.

It's hard to choose between private and protected. So I always make a function protected if there is 1% chance that derived classes may need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw a counter argument out here: instead of making the function `private`, it often should be either `protected` or also `virtual`.
Take the case where the calling or usage of the API is fine (aka the `public` functions are fine), but the implementation of the class is insufficient, or needs to be extended.
You would (of course) derive the base class, and provide new definitions for the exposed `public` functions you need to change.

The first issue is if the derived class doesn't have enough access to internal variables or helper functions to implement the improvement. I.e., to rewrite the exposed api function, it would be impossible with out the helper functions. To borrow [Nawaz's excellent answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506138/), since I'd pass some externally defined class `SomeClass` as a param to the `public`-ly exposed api `void DoWork(SomeClass param)`, and validate it with a helper function `bool IsValidParam(SomeClass param)`, if I needed to rewrite `DoWork`, it would be a pain without the existing helper functions, such as `IsValidParam`, which can only be done as `protected`.

The second issue is if you rather need to overwrite an internal function, rather than re-implement the entire public-facing calling function. In this case, you can declare your internal helper functions `virtual`. [See also When to use Private Virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170688). Like the above example, if I changed `SomeClass`, or a derivative, or under a different context need different (stricter? looser?) validation, I might only override `virtual IsValidParam`, and leave the `DoWork` function alone. In general, if you might inherit a class, or use it as a base, [it's better to make it's functions `virtual` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21076030/).

Depending on the nature of the software, or the design of the architechure, it may be useful, in early stages, to declare all functions `public virtual` or/then `protected virtual` as you limit the exposed api. Then lastly, pull out the `virtual` or declare it `private` as required. But while not restricted, it makes downstream improvements easier; especially if  it reduces need to edit already "fixed" or hard to change libraries.