# C++ overloading a base class internal call

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I wanted to override an internal call in a base class and keep the same interface and general algorithm.  The changes depend on the state of the object and thus can't just be set once in the constructor.  Is there a way to get this to work? Or perhaps a design pattern for this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
private:
    virtual void internalCall()
    {
        cout << "Class X" << endl;
    }
public:
    X()
    {
        internalCall();
    }
    void externalCall()
    {
        internalCall();
    }
};

class Y : public X
{
protected:
    virtual void internalCall2()
    {
        cout << "Class Y2" << endl;
    }
    virtual void internalCall()
    {
        cout << "Class Y" << endl;
        internalCall2();
    }
    public:
    Y() : X() {}

};

int main()
{
    Y y;

    y.externalCall();

    return 0;
}
```

Desired output:

Class Y

Class Y2

Class Y

Class Y2

Actual output:

Class X

Class Y

Class Y2

On my machine:

Class X

Class X

Comment: Post some code that actually compiles and you'll see the expected output. See this example: http://ideone.com/GN4jeh

Comment: Please show the actual code you had for this problem, what you've posted works fine: http://ideone.com/0K9LX7

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170688/private-virtual-method-in-c

Comment: So obviously my code is more complex, but I've reproduced half of it when the internal call is in the constructor.  I'm still getting different behavior with the last call too, not sure what is going on.  http://ideone.com/EzLRyG

Comment: @Envy - What did you expect this to do?  `X() {internalCall();}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling `internalCall()` from the constructor of `X`. Even though it's a virtual function, at the time the constructor for `X` is called, `Y` hasn't been created yet - so you get `X`'s `internalCall()`.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of that one, but I still don't get why on my machine I get Class X Class X

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about your environment. I can't replicate your output: http://ideone.com/h0qjTM