# Why private method overwrites base class public virtual method(with public inheritance)?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Example code

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
    public :
     A() {}
     virtual void F() { std::cout << "A::f";}
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
     B() {}


    private:
      void F()  { std::cout << "B::f"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A * ptr = &b;
    ptr->F();
    return 0;
}
```

Method `F()` from class B overrides `A::F()` despite fact it's in private section not public. Why I cannot have private method `B::F()` which doesn't overrides `A::F()` ?

If virtuals works without checking `private/public` sections, maybe there should be any warning or error thrown?

Comment: Why would you want such a thing? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Not quite a dup like the one I closed with, but highly related and provides excellent rationale https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722824/c-override-private-pure-virtual-method-as-public

Comment: How would you then distinguish between these functions? `void B::G() { F(); }` - which `F`?

Comment: With namespace always  `void B::G() { B::F(); }`.

Comment: @s.paszko Then, I don't understand your point. Why don't you simple name your private function a different way than `F`?

Comment: private/public are access specifiers -- they only control who outside your class is allowed to access the function.  It has no bearing on the overRIDE (not overWRITE) mechanism in any way.